# Create new row for a ppt table XSLFTable without losing the cell style

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am trying to create new rows to an existing sample table in powerpoint slide with apache poi without losing the format, but still can not get it.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dDniU.png)

I am expecting when adding a row to have a new one with same style from the last one, however is not keepng the style.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/62iVj.png)

I was triying to do this, but I can't beacuse is not possible to have an instance of XSLFTable. Trying to search an answer in another topic but other scenarios are related to XSSFTable that allows to keep style.

```
            XSLFTableRow oldRow = table.getRows().get(1);
            CTRow ctrow = CTRow.Factory.parse(oldRow.getXmlObject().newInputStream());
            XSLFTableRow newRow = new XSLFTableRow(ctrow, table); //Not possible to do this for ppt table

            XSLFTableCell cell = newRow.addCell();
            XSLFTextParagraph paragraph = cell.addNewTextParagraph();
            XSLFTextRun textRun = paragraph.addNewTextRun();
            textRun.setText("User 2");
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hi @AxelRichter could you please let me know if is possible to keep styles in xslftable in ppt? Thanks.

Comment: An answer highly depends on used Apache POI version. Which version are you using? And if it is not current 5.2.5, why?

Comment: @AxelRichter currently using these dependencies:                                
      <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
      <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
      <version>5.2.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
      <artifactId>poi-ooxml-full</artifactId>
      <version>5.2.4</version>
    </dependency>
Should I upgrade to 5.2.5?

Comment: "Should I upgrade to 5.2.5?": Yes you always should use the last stable version. But  5.2.4 is current enough for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Text tables, such as Word tables as well as PowerPoint tables, really are beasts. And Apache POI developers made very different and sometimes not really understandable decisions to handle those beasts.

For PowerPoint tables there is [XSLFTable.addRow](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/4.1/org/apache/poi/xslf/usermodel/XSLFTable.html#addRow--) to add a new row to a present table. But that only adds a new empty row having a default height, see [XSLFTable.java](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/poi/tags/REL_5_2_4/poi-ooxml/src/main/java/org/apache/poi/xslf/usermodel/XSLFTable.java?view=markup#l155).

To have a full copy of the previous row, one could call [XSLFTableRow](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/poi/tags/REL_5_2_4/poi-ooxml/src/main/java/org/apache/poi/xslf/usermodel/XSLFTableRow.java?view=markup#l40) constructor `XSLFTableRow(CTTableRow row, XSLFTable table)` having `CTTableRow row` a full copy of the `CTTableRow` of the previous table row. But that constructor is not public but package internally only. Why? I don't know.

Fortunately, if something is not public, there is reflection in Java to get it.

So we could do the same as `XSLFTable.addRow` does using  `CTTableRow row` being a full copy of the `CTTableRow` of the previous table row.

After that we have a new table row being an exact copy of the previous table row.

Complete example:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.xslf.usermodel.*;

public class PPTXAddTableRow {
    
 static XSLFTableRow addTableRow(XSLFTable table) throws Exception {
  XSLFTableRow lastRow = table.getRows().get(table.getNumberOfRows()-1);
  org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.main.CTTableRow ctTableRowLastRow = lastRow.getXmlObject();
  
  java.lang.reflect.Field __table = XSLFTable.class.getDeclaredField("_table");
  __table.setAccessible(true);
  org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.main.CTTable _table = (org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.main.CTTable)__table.get(table);
  org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.main.CTTableRow ctTableRowNew = _table.addNewTr();
  ctTableRowNew.set(ctTableRowLastRow.copy());
  
  java.lang.reflect.Constructor constructor = XSLFTableRow.class.getDeclaredConstructor(org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.main.CTTableRow.class, XSLFTable.class);
  constructor.setAccessible(true);
  XSLFTableRow newRow = (XSLFTableRow)constructor.newInstance(ctTableRowNew, table);
  
  java.lang.reflect.Field __rows = XSLFTable.class.getDeclaredField("_rows");
  __rows.setAccessible(true);
  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  java.util.List<XSLFTableRow> _rows = (java.util.List<XSLFTableRow>)__rows.get(table);
  _rows.add(newRow);
  
  java.lang.reflect.Method updateRowColIndexes = XSLFTable.class.getDeclaredMethod("updateRowColIndexes");
  updateRowColIndexes.setAccessible(true);
  updateRowColIndexes.invoke(table);  
  
  return newRow;  
 }
     
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  XMLSlideShow slideShow = new XMLSlideShow(new FileInputStream("./TableSample.pptx"));
  
  for (XSLFSlide slide : slideShow.getSlides()) {
   for (XSLFShape shape : slide.getShapes()) {
    if (shape instanceof XSLFTable) {
     XSLFTable table = (XSLFTable)shape;
     XSLFTableRow newTableRow = addTableRow(table);
     for (XSLFTableCell cell : newTableRow.getCells()) {
      cell.setText("new text");
     }       
    }       
   }      
  }
    
  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("./TableSampleNew.pptx");
  slideShow.write(out);
  out.close();
  slideShow.close();
 }
}
```

Note `XSLFTableCell.setText` is used here to simplify. But that looses possible text paragraph and text run formats. So probably the text paragraphs and text runs of the `XSLFTableCell`-`XSLFTextShape` needs to be used instead of `XSLFTableCell.setText`.

Comment: Generally the `CT` classes aren't exposed in the public API, that's why the other constructor is hidden. Ideally people would contribute new public APIs that hide all the CT stuff, but it doesn't happen nearly as often as you might hope/expect....

Comment: @Gagravarr: Well consistency is not Apache POI's thing, is it? See [**public** XWPFTableRow(org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTRow row,
                    XWPFTable table)](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/XWPFTableRow.html#XWPFTableRow-org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTRow-org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFTable-) ;-).